# How to get http response for failure readiness check in kubectl

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl

I am wondering what command I should use to grab the *http response* for the pod *failure readiness check*.

This is how I debug and being blocked by only get http status but not knowing the exact error response.

```
kubectl get pods/app

app                   1/1       Running            3          18h
```

It seems there are lots of **restart** happening on the pod and then I guess I need to use describe to see what triggers the restart.

```
kubectl describe pod app
```

`Warning      Unhealthy   Readiness probe failed: HTTP probe failed with statuscode: 503`

There are several reasons can lead to 503. I would like to get http response for that and I cant find any argument to include that.

Here is the readiness probe definition:

```
readinessProbe:
       httpGet:
           path: /diagnostic/ready
           port: liveness-port
       initialDelaySeconds: 10
       timeoutSeconds: 3
       failureThreshold: 80
       periodSeconds: 3
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Have you considered putting curl on the container and using an `Exec` style health check? Then you would have the ability to `curl -vo /proc/1/fd/1 localhost:whatever/whatever/else` before deciding about a-ok or not. I recognize that's not what you asked, but I was just curious if you had considered it

Comment: Do you have something in the logs?

Comment: What is in `readinessProbe` section in manifest yaml file?

Comment: @Nickolay updated :) @whites11 yeah, it has some logs but it is not that meaningful. Coz the app is killed by replication set. @matthew Yeah, I am considering to increase `initialDelaySeconds`, so I can have a chance to exec the container, but I am not sure is there a better way to do that.